# The bubble function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In the finite element method and more precisely the MINI element method in two dimensions, they use a function called the "bubble function" which is related to a triangle K of the space meshing and is defined using the following basis functions related as well to the triangle K:
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_1(X)&=1-x-y\\
\phi_2(X)&=x\\
\phi_3(X)&=y\\
\end{align*}
$$ 
Where $X=(x,y)$ is a point of the boundary of $K$. Now in all articles and books I consult, they define the bubble function as following:
$$
\phi_b(X)=27\phi_1(X)\phi_2(X)\phi_3(X)
$$
My problem is I dont get where the 27 came from, I tried to use interpolation functions but I'm not sure if the term 27 comes actually from an interpolation !! Does any one have a clue or maybe the answer ? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you are considering the product $a·b·c$ for positive $a,b,c$ with $a+b+c=1$. The range of that expression can be bounded above via the inequality of the arithmetic and geometric mean
$$
\sqrt[3]{a·b·c}\le\frac{a+b+c}3=\frac13
$$
and this bound is met for $a=b=c=\frac13$. Thus the range is $[0,\frac1{27}]$.

Or in other terms, $27·a·b·c$ has the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes your answer makes a perfect sense, because $\phi_b$ will be used next in my work as basis function and it's usually preferable to work with a uniform basis. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

A little late. The maximum of  $\phi_1*\phi_2*\phi_3$ is achieved at the barycenter of $K$, where each term is $\frac{1}{3}$. The $3^3$ scaling doesn't really matter but it makes the DOF look nicer.